# How can I make my function which checks which values are not ordered in ascending order faster?

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I wrote a function which checks which values in a vector are not ordered in an ascending order. So each element in a vector is checked if it is higher than all of the elements to its left.

I then used this function for grouped data but it takes a very long time (around 6-7 minutes). My original data has nearly 3 million of rows and 13,480 groups.

My code:

```
  check_which_not_ordered <- function(x) {  

      res <- rep(NA, length(x))

      for(i in 1:length(x)) {
         for (j in 1:i) {
         res[i] <- all(x[i] >= x[1:j])
         }
      }

  return(res) 

  }

  setDT(dt)[, ordered := check_which_not_ordered(no_of_reviews), 
            by = .(country, id)]
```

Small data sample:

```
  dtt <- data.frame(country = c(rep("USA", 10), rep("Canada", 10)),
             id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)),
             no_of_reviews = c(c(10, 12, 3, 4, 13), 
                             c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                             c(7, 9, NA, 7, NA),
                             c(NA, 7, 2, 9, 10)))
```

The output checks which elements are not sorted in ascending order as FALSE correctly. I wonder if I could achieve the same result faster?

Comment: Why use a loop and check for the whole vector? If the value to your left is higher than you are alreay out of order, so **lag(x) <= x** would suffice, package that in a lapply() type function and you should be done.

Comment: do you need the `j` loop? or just `for(i in 1:length(x)) res[i] <- all(x[i] > x[1:i])`

Comment: @Fnguyen I do not think using lag function would give me the desired output. For example, if I analyze vector c(10, 12, 3, 4, 13), then the result should be c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE). If I understand your suggestion correctly, checking only one value to the left would give me c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE).

Comment: @chinsoon12 you're completely right, the `j` loop is not necessary. However it does not make the calculations faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is:

```
DT[, nor := replace(no_of_reviews, is.na(no_of_reviews), -Inf)][,
    o4 := cummax(no_of_reviews) & no_of_reviews >= cummax(nor), .(country, id)][,
        nor := NULL]
```

output:

```
    country id no_of_reviews ordered    o4
 1:     USA  1            10    TRUE  TRUE
 2:     USA  1            12    TRUE  TRUE
 3:     USA  1             3   FALSE FALSE
 4:     USA  1             4   FALSE FALSE
 5:     USA  1            13    TRUE  TRUE
 6:     USA  2             2    TRUE  TRUE
 7:     USA  2             3    TRUE  TRUE
 8:     USA  2             4    TRUE  TRUE
 9:     USA  2             5    TRUE  TRUE
10:     USA  2             6    TRUE  TRUE
11:  Canada  3             7    TRUE  TRUE
12:  Canada  3             9    TRUE  TRUE
13:  Canada  3            NA      NA    NA
14:  Canada  3             7   FALSE FALSE
15:  Canada  3            NA      NA    NA
16:  Canada  4            NA      NA    NA
17:  Canada  4             7      NA    NA
18:  Canada  4             2   FALSE FALSE
19:  Canada  4             9      NA    NA
20:  Canada  4            10      NA    NA
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(country = c(rep("USA", 10), rep("Canada", 10)),
    id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)),
    no_of_reviews = c(c(10, 12, 3, 4, 13), 
        c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
        c(7, 9, NA, 7, NA),
        c(NA, 7, 2, 9, 10)))

#OP's function
check_which_not_ordered <- function(x) {  
    res <- rep(NA, length(x))
    for(i in 1:length(x)) {
        res[i] <- all(x[i] >= x[1:i])
    }
    res
}
DT[, ordered := check_which_not_ordered(no_of_reviews), .(country, id)]
```

Comment: Brilliant, gives the right result and works instantaneously. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Use the `cummax()` function, and see if each element is equal to the cumulative max at the same location. Then put the NA's back in.

```r
library(microbenchmark)
dtt <- data.frame(country = c(rep("USA", 10), rep("Canada", 10)),
                  id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)),
                  no_of_reviews = c(c(10, 12, 3, 4, 13), 
                                    c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                                    c(7, 9, NA, 7, NA),
                                    c(NA, 7, 2, 9, 10)))


check_which_not_ordered <- function(x) {  

  res <- rep(NA, length(x))

  for(i in 1:length(x)) {
    for (j in 1:i) {
      res[i] <- all(x[i] >= x[1:j])
    }
  }

  return(res) 

}

check_which_not_ordered2 <- function(x) {
  na_inds <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na_inds] <- min(x) - 1
  res <- x == cummax(x)
  res[na_inds] <- NA
  return(res)
}


x = dtt$no_of_reviews

microbenchmark(check_which_not_ordered(x), check_which_not_ordered2(x))
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>                         expr   min       lq      mean   median       uq
#>   check_which_not_ordered(x) 97185 128197.5 167051.89 133333.5 135901.5
#>  check_which_not_ordered2(x)   790   1185.0  24845.53   1580.0   1975.0
#>      max neval
#>  3863309   100
#>  2304395   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: just to feedback that the 3 functions do not return the same values for Canada and id=4. see `setDT(dtt)[, ordered := check_which_not_ordered(no_of_reviews), .(country, id)] [, 
    o2 := check_which_not_ordered2(no_of_reviews), .(country, id)][, 
        o3 := check_which_not_ordered3(no_of_reviews), .(country, id)]`. it is due to the presence of NAs. and see also `all(c(TRUE, NA)); all(c(FALSE, NA)); any(c(TRUE, NA)); any(c(FALSE, NA))`

Comment: It was a mistake/typo for me to leave that 3rd function in. I noticed issues with it and originally I thought that method might be a bit faster, but it wasn't. I removed it from the timing but had forgotten to remove the function itself. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @ClancyStats I could not replicate my results using the `check_which_not_ordered2() ` function. This is only a problem for vectors with NAs